# Verify bearer token API with the MEAN stack

Tags: angular, api, observable, mean-stack, bearer-token

I'm working on an angular application and I struggle to implement the api's bearer token validation.

The process looks like this:

1. Authguard ask the AuthService to validate the locally stored authentification token

```
      canActivate(): boolean {
        if(this.AuthService.isAuthenticated()){
          return true;
        } else{
          this.router.navigate(['elsewhere/maybeToSwimmingPool']);
        }
      }
```

2. The AuthService call isAuthenticated method who'll fetch if the token is valid from the api

```
      isAuthenticated(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
          this.verifyToken().subscribe(
            data => {return data;}
          )
        }else{
          return false;
        }
      }

      verifyToken() : Observable<boolean>{
        const url = this.apiVerifyTokenUrl + '/' + localStorage.getItem('token');
        return this.http.get<boolean>(apiVerifyTokenUrl, this.httpOptions);
      }
```

3. The Api decode the token, check if the user exist in the database and return a boolean

```
    exports.verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
     try{
      verifiedJwt = jwt.verify(req.params.token, secret);
      let userId= verifiedJwt.userId;
      User.findOne({_id: userId})
      .then(() => res.status(200).send('true'))
      .catch(error => res.status(200).send('false'));
     }
     catch(e){
      res.status(200).send('false');
     }
    }
```

I'm not sure what monstrosity I programmed. Maybe the Authguard can't wait asynchronously the observable?
I really don't know what's wrong with my code anb I hope you guys can find the deadly bug and give me advise about my code? These are my firststep with mean stack and I welcome every advise, critisism :)

Have a good day,
Eelke Johnson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the asyncronous code in your [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) guard, so you should not return `boolean`, and instead return `Observable<boolean>`. Similarly, your isAuthenticated method should not call `subscribe`, but instead return an observable. The reason your code doesn't work is that the Guard doesn't wait for all subscribe blocks to finish. Instead the Guard immediately returns some value (synchronously) and your token checking happens later.

I imagine that it would work if you structure it like this. I didn't touch your backend though.

1. In the guard you return the observable of the result and if the user is not authenticated, do your side effect in [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator. The guard will subscribe to the return value of `canActivate` function.

```js
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.AuthService.isAuthenticated().pipe(
    tap( isAuthenticated => !isAuthenticated ?  this.router.navigate(['elsewhere/maybeToSwimmingPool']): 0)
  );
```

Here instead of subscribing, you just return an observable.

```js
isAuthenticated(): Obsevable<boolean>{
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if(token){
     return this.verifyToken(token)
  }
}

verifyToken(token) : Observable<boolean>{
  const url = this.apiVerifyTokenUrl + '/' + token
  return this.http.get<boolean>(apiVerifyTokenUrl, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was exactly this ! You can't know how grateful I am :D I suspected the problem came from the asynchronous nature of observable but I had no idea how to fix this ! Thank you so much

Comment: can you please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) then? There is a green tick right below the voting.